# Returning values of a 'ReturnList' without the key in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

So I have this Serializers

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('name', 'thumbnail', 'source_url', 'duration')

class SingleCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies = MovieSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MoviesCategories
        fields = ('movies',)
```

The Movie model has a relationship with the movies categories as follows

```
category = models.ForeignKey(MoviesCategories, related_name="movies", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Now when I try this 
`serializer = SingleCategorySerializer(movie_category, many=True)`, the result of `serializer.data` is

```
[
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "name": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
            "thumbnail": "https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-poster-2.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://dl.tehmovies.org/94/10/Star.Wars/Star.Wars.Episode.II.Attack.of.the.Clones.2002.1080p.5.1CH.Tehmovies.ir.mkv",
            "duration": "05:30:09"
        },
        {
            "name": "Star Wars II",
            "thumbnail": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51TEG6X589L.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://dl.tehmovies.org/94/10/Star.Wars/Star.Wars.Episode.II.Attack.of.the.Clones.2002.1080p.5.1CH.Tehmovies.ir.mkv",
            "duration": "05:32:26"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I only want the values of the `movies` to be returned. Like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
        "thumbnail": "https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-poster-2.jpg",
        "source_url": "http://dl.tehmovies.org/94/10/Star.Wars/Star.Wars.Episode.II.Attack.of.the.Clones.2002.1080p.5.1CH.Tehmovies.ir.mkv",
        "duration": "05:30:09"
    },
    {
        "name": "Star Wars II",
        "thumbnail": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51TEG6X589L.jpg",
        "source_url": "http://dl.tehmovies.org/94/10/Star.Wars/Star.Wars.Episode.II.Attack.of.the.Clones.2002.1080p.5.1CH.Tehmovies.ir.mkv",
        "duration": "05:32:26"
    }
]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Michael, It is not called Star Wars II it is called attack of the clones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your post , `serializer.data` returns

```
[
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "name": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
            "thumbnail": "https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy-poster-2.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://dl.tehmovies.org/94/10/Star.Wars/Star.Wars.Episode.II.Attack.of.the.Clones.2002.1080p.5.1CH.Tehmovies.ir.mkv",
            "duration": "05:30:09"
        },
        {
            "name": "Star Wars II",
            "thumbnail": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51TEG6X589L.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://dl.tehmovies.org/94/10/Star.Wars/Star.Wars.Episode.II.Attack.of.the.Clones.2002.1080p.5.1CH.Tehmovies.ir.mkv",
            "duration": "05:32:26"
         }
    ]
}
]
```

use simple list indexing. `serializer.data` returns a list with one element. So to get that you would call `serializer.data[0]`. That element is a dictionary. So  to access that, just use `serializer.data[0]["movies"]`. This says, "hey python, I want the first element of this list (serializer.data), and from that element....OOH, its a `dict`. Can I have the item with a key of `"movies"`. "

Comment: Thanks alot. I had tried it too just forgot to place it in code `print("Got a response ", serializer.data[0]['movies'])
        return Response(serializer.data)`

Comment: No problem, Just accept the answer So I know that this question is done

Comment: 52 seconds remaining (: